# aws events put-targets response is positive but the trigger is not added

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I am deploying a lambda function and I would like to call it daily. I realize that even though I get no errors, the final deployment step somehow fails

```
aws events put-rule --name "daily_lambda_rule" \ 
                    --schedule-expression 'rate(15 minutes)'


aws lambda add-permission --function-name daily_lambda_rule \
                          --statement-id daily_lambda_function_scheduler \
                          --action 'lambda:InvokeFunction' \
                          --principal events.amazonaws.com \
                          --source-arn arn:aws:events:us-east-1:your-account-id:rule/daily_lambda_rule

aws events put-targets --rule daily_lambda_rule \
                        --targets "Id": "1","Arn":"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:your-account-id:function:myfun"
```

The last output is:

```
{
    "FailedEntryCount": 0,
    "FailedEntries": []
}
```

This suggests that everything went good, yet when I click on the lambda function, I see no sign that cloudwatch has added this trigger. Also, manually adding the trigger works fine.

Using `boto3` yields the same results:

```
import boto3
events_client = boto3.client('events')
lambda_arn = 'arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:my-account-id:function:myfunction'
event_rule_name ='daily_lambda_rule'

scheduled_lambda = [
    {
        'Id': "myfunction", # lambda name
        'Arn': lambda_arn,
    }
]

response = events_client.put_targets(Rule=event_rule_name,
                          Targets=scheduled_lambda)
```

Where/what could be the error that prevents the script from `adding the trigger` to the lambda function?

Hereby some links I unsuccesfully checked:
https://towardsdatascience.com/loading-reddit-posts-using-aws-lambda-and-cloudwatch-events-9edb03ba4c14

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/events/put-targets.html

boto3 - put_targest
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-cloudwatch-put_targets.py.html

boto3- example
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/python/example_code/lambda/scheduled_lambda/scheduled_lambda.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made 2 observations:
Firstly: in the CLI commands, while putting the rule, enable the state as well:

```
aws events put-rule --name "daily_lambda_rule" \ 
                    --schedule-expression 'rate(15 minutes)'
                    --state 'ENABLED'
```

Secondly: in Python Boto3 script you skipped the Lambda Permissions step - it is mandatory to attach the trigger to the Lambda. Following is the full code which is working for me:

```py
import boto3

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')
events_client = boto3.client('events')

lambda_name = "live_scoreboard"
fn_role = 'arn:aws:iam::{}:role/lambda_basic_execution'.format(MY_ACCOUNT_ID)

create_res = lambda_client.create_function(
  FunctionName=lambda_name,
  Runtime='python3.8',
  Role=fn_role,
  Handler="{0}.lambda_handler".format(lambda_name),
  Code={'ZipFile': open("CODE_FILE_PATH.ZIP", 'rb').read(), },
)
fn_arn = create_res['FunctionArn']
cron = "0/5 9-18 * 2 ? 2020"
rule_name = "sb_".format(lambda_name)

rule_res = events_client.put_rule(
  Name=rule_name,
  ScheduleExpression='cron({})'.format(cron),
  State='ENABLED',
)
lambda_client.add_permission(
  FunctionName=lambda_name,
  StatementId="{0}-Event".format(rule_name),
  Action='lambda:InvokeFunction',
  Principal='events.amazonaws.com',
  SourceArn=rule_res['RuleArn'],
)
events_client.put_targets(
  Rule=rule_name,
  Targets=[
    {
      'Id': "target_" + (SOME_ID),
      'Arn': fn_arn,
    },
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `region`

```bash
aws events put-rule --name "daily_lambda_rule" \ 
    --region="us-east-1" \
    --schedule-expression 'rate(15 minutes)'

aws lambda add-permission --function-name daily_lambda_rule \
    --region="us-east-1" \
    --statement-id daily_lambda_function_scheduler \
    --action 'lambda:InvokeFunction' \
    --principal events.amazonaws.com \
    --source-arn arn:aws:events:us-east-1:your-account-id:rule/daily_lambda_rule

aws events put-targets --rule daily_lambda_rule \
    --region="us-east-1" \
    --targets "Id": "1","Arn":"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:your-account-id:function:myfun"
```